# Speech output appended twice

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition

I want to use native browser voice to speech api. But I am getting strange results. This is my code. It uses jquery and

https://sdkcarlos.github.io/sites/artyom.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
        <script src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/artyom.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="startRecognition();" value="Recognize text" />
        <input type="button" onclick="stopRecognition();" value="stop recognition" />
        <input type="button" onclick="clearX();" value="clear" />
        <script>

            var buffer = "";

            var settings = {
                continuous:false, // Don't stop never because i have https connection
                onResult:function(text){
                    // text = the recognized text
                    //console.log(text);
                    buffer = text;
                },
                onStart:function(){
                    //console.log("Dictation started by the user");
                },
                onEnd:function() {
                    //alert("Dictation stopped by the user");
                    jQuery("#out").append("<div>" + buffer + "</div>");
                    UserDictation.start();
                }
            };

            var UserDictation = artyom.newDictation(settings);

            function startRecognition(){
                //UserDictation.start();
            }

            function stopRecognition(){
                //UserDictation.stop();
            }

            UserDictation.start();

            function clearX() {
                jQuery("#out").empty();
            }
        </script>
        <div id="out"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Except when I try this, the results it gives looks like it gets repeated works/phrases. Like if I say `computer`, it gives me `computercomputer`. Or if I say `what's the expected price?` it gives me like `what'swhat'swhat'sthewhat's the what's the what's the expected what's the expected price, etc...`.

There is this page too

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html

which seems to get the same problem as me.

But then there is also a demo of the same js library on this other site

https://apps.golightlyplus.com/speech-to-text-demo/

Which seems to show the result really nicely.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to clear the buffer after you appended it. I would not use buffer at all, you can just append the result directly in onResult.

Comment: The buffer is getting set with `=` though not appending with `+=`.

Comment: What looks strange to me is that your are calling `UserDictation.start();` again on end, I am just asking myself why that does not result in an infinite loop…

Comment: Its so that i get the final text when the user stops talking, then it starts listening again so to simulate continuous listening.

Comment: Does work correctly for the first time, if you do not start it again immediately?

Comment: with `jQuery("#out").append("<div>" + buffer + "</div>")` you definitely appending text. Does the `result/text` definitely not contain the whole phrase, but is called more often?

Comment: what happens if you set `continuous` to `true` and don't start again on end?

Comment: It does not work correctly all the time, even the first time. And even though I append it, the new appends go on new lines (since its in divs), but the repeats get shown together inside the div itself (on the same line). And even if I set continuous to tree, its the same behaviour.

Comment: if you look here https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API, you can see comments saying `This Web Speech API is making double entry in mobile browsers but pc well` and `for me it seems that word are repeating multiple time on mobile .. Do you have any solution of this Problem..`